# PayPal IPN Unsubscribing

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I'm using the PayPal IPN (Instant Payment Notification) api for subscriptions but I can't find a way to let users UNSUBSCRIBE themselves. The solutions I've found so far require the customer to login to paypal but what about the users who paid with a creditcard/don't have paypal? This is very frustrating. I've the entire day today looking for a solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a saved button you can 'view' the button and there is a link to create an unsubscribe button.  I do not know of a way to create an unsubscribe button if you don't use a saved button.

Answer (score 0):

The subscription process is initiated in your site because it need to carry the product information from your site. After the subscription process done, the buyer should see this in their paypal account and can unsubscribe from there.

The reason for this maybe because you cannot store the buyer's paypal username and password and use it to fetch that buyer's subscription list from paypal. That's why it's must be done by the buyer in the paypal website, not in your site.

Comment: what about for people who don't have a paypal account and user their credit card. As for paypal users I was hoping for unsubscribing to work similar to the subscribing process. I 'POST' a form to the paypal site, including the subscriber ID (provided in IPN response data) and whatever else is needed, the user is taken to the paypal site to cancel subscription, and then paypal sends the user back to my webpage with some data about the user. From there I can update my database. I don't think this is possible at all so in the future I will go with Google checkout or some other payment gateway.